# Where does Rav Hai Gaon explain the meaning of the phrase צורבא מרבנן?

Tags: sources-mekorot, aramaic, oral-torah, geonim, bava-metzia

In the Steinsaltz Edition of Masechet Bava Metzia perek Eilu Metziot there is a side note that רב האי גאון explains the shoresh of צ-ר-ב as meaning a rock, stone (from Arabic). 
This root is more often said to mean something burned through the contact with fire. 
I am looking for the source - where does רב האי גאון explain the meaning of the word צורבא?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is found in *Shaarei Teshuva* ch. 84

> לרבינו האי ז"ל
>   וששאלתם צורב"א מרבנן הוא כמו צרב'ת השחין דבר חם המתחמם באשה של תורה האי צורבא מרבנן דרתח אורייתיה קא מרתחא ליה שנאמר הלא כה דברי כאש ד"א צורבא מרבנן קשה בערבי קורין לחטים הקשות חנטא צריבא (צ"ל מנוגה) (מובהק) נגדו בערו גחלי אש ותרגם מזיו יקריה מבהקין גרסינן בשקלים תבוא מארה לאשה שיש לה בעל ואינה מתקשטת ותבוא מארה לאשה שאין לה בעל ומתקשטת ותבוא מארה לצורבא מרבנן דלא מתקשט בכבודה של תורה.

He given two explanations: Either *tsurba* means heated, and refers to those "heated by the fire of Torah", or it means hard.

Comment: Is the original source for this preserved? Which work authored by Rav Hai Gaon does it come from?

Comment: @MichaelS I should have clarified: Shaarei Teshuva is the name of a compendium of Geonic responsa. It should not be confused with Rabbenu Yonah Gerondi's work of the same title. The wording indicates that this was a responsum of R. Hai.